# Can I resize an entire docx file at once?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, docx

Is there a way to completely resize a docx file all at once? Here's what I am trying to do:
I edit a 450+ page journal for my work. The journal is comprised of approximately 30-40 individual docx and some bonus pdfs because why not. The docx files start life as legal sized documents as they serve other purposes before it's journal time. I then have to change each file from 8 1/2" X 14" to 6.25" x 9.25". Changing the page size is easy enough but now I have to go back through each new docx (some are 40+ pages long) and reduce the font sizes, table sizes, headers & footers, etc, to make it fit the new page size. Is there a way to reduce the ENTIRE document at once? This would save me so much time and effort. Also, I'm using Microsoft Word 2010 at work and 2013 at home.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just print to PDF, then open that PDF and then print on a particular size paper?

Comment: ^ Or print to PDF AT the desired page size from the get-go...

Comment: One trick that is very similar to @Mokubai suggestion is to print it, then use the Acrobat Reader printing option for page sizing "to fit" and *print to PDF* (instead of paper). Then you have a complete PDF with desired page size baked in that can be archived.

Comment: But I am not the one that is printing it. The entire file, when it is finished, needs to be saved as a 6.25 x 9.25 pdf. Can you change the size of a pdf file, without printing it? Like could I save my legal size docx as a legal size pdf and then change the pdf to the smaller page size? Because I can't figure out how to change a pdf size either, again without printing it.

Comment: I swear there is a way to do this but I can't remember how with the 50,000 other things you can do.  "Auto page layout'.. or something like that.. Things are getting harder and harder to find.. not easier.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  Microsoft has added a really handy tool search function to the top of all their Office products now allowing you to type in the tool you're looking for. It'll find the tool, tell you where to find it, and give you a direct button to run it from the search.

Answer (score 0):

**no it's not possible**

Decreasing the size is not just font size, headers..., it's also about borders, might be line spacing, indents...
And still you should double check whether anything is messed up.

The only realistic approach - as suggested already in comments - is to convert to pdf first and decrease size of pdfs.